# Laravel 4: Return data to every view

Tags: laravel-4

is there a way that I automatically could return data to every view in laravel, so I don't have to do it in every single controller.
Like in the BaseController?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435688/php-use-database-in-mvc-view-layer-laravel-blade/19445230#19445230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, read [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views) carefully

```
View::share('name', $value);
```